# Pandas - stack time columns with time and date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have date and time data now I want to reduce this dataframe to two columns with Timestamp (date+time) in a column and value in another column

current df -

```
Date                    8 am   10 am   1 pm
-----------------------------------------------
23/02/2022              5        10    11
24/02/2022              2        17    15         
25/02/2022              7        90    175
```

desired df -

```
Timestamp                       value
----------------------------------------------
2022-02-23 00:08:00               5
2022-02-23 00:10:00               10
2022-02-23 00:13:00               11
2022-02-24 00:08:00               2
2022-02-24 00:10:00               17
2022-02-24 00:13:00               15
2022-02-25 00:08:00               7
2022-02-25 00:10:00               90
2022-02-25 00:13:00               175
```

Here is original list from which I'm creating my dataframe -

```
[['Date', '08:00', '10:00', '12:00', '14:00', '19:00', '22:00', '03:00'],
 ['23/02/2022', '140', '244', '191', '88', '263', '252', '159'],
 ['24/02/2022', '184', '235', '189', '108', '283', '300', '202'],
 ['25/02/2022', '131', '217', '135', '179', '207', '284', '177'],
 ['26/02/2022', '112', '188', '96', '139', '148', '188', '125'],
 ['27/02/2022', '130', '189', '104', '163', '210', '221', '139'],
 ['28/02/2022', '118', '89', '84', '113', '259', '234', '105'],
 ['01/03/2022', '98', '89', '77', '82', '138', '174', '71'],
 ['02/03/2022', '87', '187', '69', '118', '199', '178', '59'],
 ['03/03/2022', '90', '200', '110', '102', '180', '216', '72']]
```

Comment: Date is the index?

Comment: Can you provide the input as DataFrame constructor?

Comment: @Yefet it is a separate column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `melt` to flatten your dataframe and set `Time` as a name of the variable column. Combine columns `Date` and `Time` to create the timestamp then `sort_values` to reorder your dataframe. Finally, keep only `Timestamp` and `value` columns:

```
combine_datetime = lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['Date'] + ' ' + x['Time'], 
                                            format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')

out = (
  df.melt('Date', var_name='Time').assign(Timestamp=combine_datetime)
    .sort_values('Timestamp', ignore_index=True)[['Timestamp', 'value']]
)
print(out)

# Output
             Timestamp value
0  2022-02-23 03:00:00   159
1  2022-02-23 08:00:00   140
2  2022-02-23 10:00:00   244
3  2022-02-23 12:00:00   191
4  2022-02-23 14:00:00    88
..                 ...   ...
58 2022-03-03 10:00:00   200
59 2022-03-03 12:00:00   110
60 2022-03-03 14:00:00   102
61 2022-03-03 19:00:00   180
62 2022-03-03 22:00:00   216

[63 rows x 2 columns]
```

**Note**: For `pd.to_datetime`, I used an explicit format to avoid Pandas infer the datetime if there are any ambiguities with the day first.

Comment: the sorting is not correct it is sorting according to date first and than month for example if I add Date 2022-03-03 10:00:00 than it will come first but I want feb month Dates come first than march and so on

Comment: @SarthakBhagwat. I updated my answer can you check it, please?

Comment: I added a custom key to sort the dataframe: `lambda x: x.dt.strftime('%m%Y%d%H%M')`. You can modify it to sort your dataframe like you want.

Comment: Thanks but after using errors='coerce' and format='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M' it is working fine, you both have similar ans now I'm thinking which ans I should mark as accepted xD

Comment: So you don't need the custom key? I don't understand why you need `errors='coerce'`?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
(df
   .melt(id_vars='Date', var_name='time')
   .assign(Timestamp=lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d['Date']+' '+d['time']))
   [['Timestamp', 'value']]
   # below optional
   .sort_values(by='Timestamp').reset_index(drop=True)
 )
```

Output:

```
            Timestamp  value
0 2022-02-23 08:00:00      5
1 2022-02-23 10:00:00     10
2 2022-02-23 13:00:00     11
3 2022-02-24 08:00:00      2
4 2022-02-24 10:00:00     17
5 2022-02-24 13:00:00     15
6 2022-02-25 08:00:00      7
7 2022-02-25 10:00:00     90
8 2022-02-25 13:00:00    175
```

Comment: Great minds think alike :)

Comment: I think you should use `reset_index` if `Date` is the index

Comment: Maybe, it wasn't clear from the question, that's why I requested the constructor. I'll add a note.

Comment: @mozway its not index its a separate column

Comment: @Sarthak then do not `reset_index` ;)

Comment: @mozway can you please explain in the answer what each function is doing including lambda

Comment: `melt` reshapes the columns to rows, `assign` adds a new column with the date that results from the date and time concatenation (the `lambda` is required to access the reshaped columns. I suggest you comment all lines starting with `.` and uncomment one by one to see the intermediates

Comment: @mozway one more thing the sorting is not correct it is sorting according to date first and than month
for example if I add Date 2022-03-03 10:00:00 than it will come first but I want feb month Dates come first than march and so on .

Comment: @Sarthak `2022-02-05` (Feb 5th) will be sorted before `2022-03-05` (Mar 5th), I don't understand the issue.

Comment: @mozway I don't know somehow to_datetime function not working properly it is making march (03) as day and day as month 
here is screenshot link for the output : https://i.ibb.co/vYMkNZD/Screenshot-from-2022-03-07-15-33-09.png
After 28 feb there should be 01 march instead it is changing month field

Comment: @mozway you can check the original list from which I'm creating dataframe I've updated the question

Comment: @Sarthak works fine for me with the updated data

Answer (score 0):

Set date as index, stack and coerce  concatenated time component into datetime;

```
s =df.set_index('Date').stack().to_frame('value').reset_index()
s=s.assign(Timestamp=pd.to_datetime(s['Date'].str.cat(s['level_1'], sep =' ')))[['Timestamp', 'value']]


 

             Timestamp   value
0 2022-02-23 08:00:00      5
1 2022-02-23 10:00:00     10
2 2022-02-23 13:00:00     11
3 2022-02-24 08:00:00      2
4 2022-02-24 10:00:00     17
5 2022-02-24 13:00:00     15
6 2022-02-25 08:00:00      7
7 2022-02-25 10:00:00     90
8 2022-02-25 13:00:00    175
```